# Advanced exchange method (even and odd element exchange)

Tags: java

Can someone please help with exchange method.
I have an algorithm

---

1. Assign boolean variable b to true.
2. While b is true, perform the following steps:
   a) Assign false to b.
   b) Change i from 0 to the end of the array in step 2 and execute for each value of i:

   - if the element with the number i is larger than the element with the number i + 1 then:
     1) Swap array elements with numbers i and i + 1;
   - assign the value b to true.
3. Change i from 1 to the end of the array in step 2 and execute each value of i:

   - if the element with the number i is larger than the element with the number i + 1 then:
     1) Swap array elements with numbers i and i + 1;
   - assign the value b to true.

```
public static void firstmethod(int[] a) {
    boolean b = true; // boolean =true
    while (b = true) {
        b = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i = i + 2) //Do konca massiva A,wag 2,i i=0!
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                a[i] = a[i + 1];//menajem mestami 
                b = true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length; i = i + 2) //Do konca massiva A,wag 2,i i=0!
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                a[i] = a[i + 1];//menajem mestami 
                b = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Main problem is when im initializing array I'm getting out of bounds error.
I understand that this is because of a[i+1],but I dont understand how to fix it....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few things on a quick read:

- `while (b == true) {}`
- `for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i = i + 2) {}`
- `a[i] = a[i + 1]` is only half of a swap. You are missing `a[i + 1] = a[i]` but by now your `a[i]`
  has new value already, so you have to think a bit (or google **variable swap**).